# Vue-Moment agregar fecha en español

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, momentjs

necesito su ayuda estoy utilizando la libreria `vue-moment` para mi proyecto hecho en `VueJS`, y en ello estoy agregando toda la información en base a la siguiente documentación *https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-moment*, al momento de utilizar la libreria su idioma por defecto es en ingles.

Código en el que uso la librería:

```html
        <p>
          {{ fecha_creacion | moment("from", "now", true) }}
        </p>
```

Muestra del resultado

[image: Imagen del resultado]

Lo que intento es mostrar en la vista en idioma español.

Espero su pronta ayuda, muchas gracias.

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿de qué idioma funciona tu navegador?

Comment: lo que me envías lo utiliza en javascript, yo lo estoy utilizando dentro de la etiqueta html, mi navegador esta en español

Comment: revisa por favor: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-moment#configuration

Comment: Sigue igual amigo

Comment: Coloca todo el código que creas que es necesario para que cualquier usuario del sitio pueda reproducir tu caso :D

Comment: Vue.use(require("vue-moment"), require("moment/locale/es"));

Comment: dale editar a tu pregunta y coloca el código ahi mismo, pues en la zona de comentarios se hace difícil seguir un orden

Comment: Ya lo solucione amigo, gracias por el aporte

Comment: como lo solucionaste? que era lo que pasaba?